# iBatis multiple queries result to single model instace

Tags: java, sql, database, orm, ibatis

Generally an iBatis select query returns a new instance of the resultMap class. Is it possible to somehow pass a class' instance to SQLMapper's queryForObject method, so instead of returning a new instance, the select query populates the data in the passed instance and return.

Thanks